# How to optimize the scroll-down code in java using selenium

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, web-crawler, jsoup

I am working a project in *MAVEN* using *Java*.
I have to get a URL, scroll them down ,and get all the links of other items in this given web page.

Till now, I get the page dynamically using Selenium , and scrolling them down, and fetch the links also. But it takes too much time. Please help me in optimize that.

Example:-, I am working on a page , whose link is [here](http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/men-sports-shoes/?source=home-leftnav).

**My Questions** :-

1. Scrolling web page using selenium is very slow. How can I optimize this? (Suggest any other method
   to do the same or help me to optimize this one)

Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind response.

**Code to dynamically get and scroll the page**:-

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.common.collect.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

/**
 *
 * @author jhamb
 */
public class Scroll_down {

    private static FirefoxProfile createFirefoxProfile() {
        File profileDir = new File("/tmp/firefox-profile-dir");
        if (profileDir.exists()) {
            return new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);
        }
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        File dir = firefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk();
        try {
            profileDir.mkdirs();
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(dir, profileDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return firefoxProfile;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException{
        String url1 = "http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/men-sports-shoes/?source=home-leftnav";
        System.out.println("Fetching %s..." + url1);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(createFirefoxProfile());


        driver.get(url1);  

        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) {
                break;
            }
            jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
            String hml = driver.getPageSource();
        driver.close();


        Document document = Jsoup.parse(hml);

            Elements links = document.select("div");

        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println(link.attr("data-url"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @All Help me please. Scrolling down process takes lots of time.

Comment: what's the benefit of scrolling? how is it necessary?

Comment: @EliranMalka I am working on onlne shopping websites data, like Amazon, Flipkart etc. And, the page is load when we scroll down, it shows more products, so if I give any URL, then it scrolls till end , and then fetch all the links , that is present in it. I coded this whole functionality but that is very slow. Tell me how can I optimize this scrollong part in my code. Please.

Answer (score 1):

Well Selenium scrolling is based on Javascript. I dont know your goal with selenium though, you have no assertion to compare anything in your code ?
When you are so sure that your data fetching so fast then don't use any sleep methode. 
Sleep methods makes selenium slower, but yeah it is waiting until the element is properly loaded .....
It's up to you, what to test though

Comment: I want to scroll page down., when it reaches at the end, then by using Jsoup fetches all the inner links of other products. Do you know any other optimized method for the same ? 

If I remove sleep, then this code is not become reliable for every case. So tell me any reliable and optimized method, please.

Comment: I saw your link, and the problem is there is no limitation in product amount per page, so basically page will continue to load even after it reaches it ends. As to answer your question why dont you increase the scrolling pixel to be a bit bigger. But as I said, slow is because there is no item limit in the page !!

Comment: Can you explain your second last line, please. Can you give some implementation clue for the same, if you have better idea than mine ?

Comment: JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) {
                break;
            }
            jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
            String hml = driver.getPageSource(); This code why dont you instead of 0,200 not writing something like 0,1000, bigger == faster :D

Comment: Is changing value from 200 to 1000 creates problem in slower internet connection or not ?

Comment: Well, for me what you are trying to achive is like a contradiction.... You told me that scroll down is too slow, now I give you scroll down in bigger pixel instead of 200 to 1000. When you have slow internet connection, add more wait or implicit wait with selenium ....

Comment: Is there any way, so that I can configure selenium settings ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand what do you want with selenium config, we can do chat though?

Answer (score 0):

How about page down?

```
ele.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);   //WebElement ele = <Any existing element>
```

Repeat this till you find that particular item.