# Strange behavior of "org.apache.log4j.Logger" in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am doing *Maven project*. I made a log using **log4j**. But it shows some starnge log in the given file. I try to understand, why this strange log comes, but I didn't understand. Please help me, why this unwanted lines enter in the log file.

Please help me to remove this.

**log.properties**

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /usr/home/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/Users/aMpliFieR/Desktop/log.txt

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

I made this file by reading this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm).

**And code is**

```
public class test {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( test.class.getName() );

    public static void func(String url1, String url2) throws  InterruptedException {
        Threqad.sleep(100000000);  // Here is some process that performs recursively
        log.info( url1 + "\n" + url2 + "\n"+ ((double)loading_time)/((double)1000)+ " seconds   " + ((double)parsing_time)/((double)1000) +  " seconds   "  + ((double)processing_time)/((double)1000) + " seconds\n\n\n\n" );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { func("ANY URL1", "ANY URL2");  }
    }
}
```

**Log.txt-(some starting lines of log.txt)**

```
Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055, timeout = 120000
[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /hub/session HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /hub/session HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 105[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> POST /hub/session HTTP/1.1
>> Accept: application/json, image/png
>> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Length: 105
>> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "{"desiredCapabilities":{"platform":"ANY","browserName":"firefox","version":""},"requiredCapabilities":{}}"
<< "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other[\r][\n]"
<< "location: http://127.0.0.1:7055/hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38[\r][\n]"
<< "connection: close[\r][\n]"
<< "content-length: 0[\r][\n]"
<< "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
<< "date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:11 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
<< HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
<< location: http://127.0.0.1:7055/hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38
<< connection: close
<< content-length: 0
<< server: httpd.js
<< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:11 GMT
Redirect requested to location 'http://127.0.0.1:7055/hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38'
Redirecting to 'http://127.0.0.1:7055/hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38' via {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055
Connection 0.0.0.0:59145<->127.0.0.1:7055 closed
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 2 to execute request
Sending request: GET /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38 HTTP/1.1
>> "GET /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> GET /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38 HTTP/1.1
>> Accept: application/json, image/png
>> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
<< "connection: close[\r][\n]"
<< "content-length: 462[\r][\n]"
<< "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
<< "date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:11 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<< connection: close
<< content-length: 462
<< server: httpd.js
<< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:11 GMT
<< "{"name":"getSessionCapabilities","sessionId":"bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38","status":0,"value":{"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"browserName":"firefox","handlesAlerts":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"nativeEvents":true,"platform":"WINNT","rotatable":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"version":"20.0","webStorageEnabled":true,"applicationCacheEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"browserConnectionEnabled":true,"acceptSslCerts":true}}"
Connection 0.0.0.0:59146<->127.0.0.1:7055 shut down
Released connection is not reusable.
Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Connection 0.0.0.0:59146<->127.0.0.1:7055 closed
Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055, timeout = 120000
[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/url HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/url HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 74[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/url HTTP/1.1
>> Accept: application/json, image/png
>> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Length: 74
>> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "{"url":"http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/men-loafers/?source=home-leftnav"}"
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
<< "connection: close[\r][\n]"
<< "content-length: 87[\r][\n]"
<< "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
<< "date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:21 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<< connection: close
<< content-length: 87
<< server: httpd.js
<< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:21 GMT
<< "{"name":"get","sessionId":"bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38","status":0,"value":""}"
Connection 0.0.0.0:59147<->127.0.0.1:7055 shut down
Released connection is not reusable.
Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Connection 0.0.0.0:59147<->127.0.0.1:7055 closed
Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055, timeout = 120000
[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 47[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> Accept: application/json, image/png
>> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Length: 47
>> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "{"args":[""],"script":"window.scrollBy(0,250)"}"
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
<< "connection: close[\r][\n]"
<< "content-length: 99[\r][\n]"
<< "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
<< "date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:34 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<< connection: close
<< content-length: 99
<< server: httpd.js
<< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:34 GMT
<< "{"name":"executeScript","sessionId":"bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38","status":0,"value":null}"
Connection 0.0.0.0:59202<->127.0.0.1:7055 shut down
Released connection is not reusable.
Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Connection 0.0.0.0:59202<->127.0.0.1:7055 closed
Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055, timeout = 120000
[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 47[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> Accept: application/json, image/png
>> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Length: 47
>> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "{"args":[""],"script":"window.scrollBy(0,200)"}"
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
<< "connection: close[\r][\n]"
<< "content-length: 99[\r][\n]"
<< "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
<< "date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:34 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<< connection: close
<< content-length: 99
<< server: httpd.js
<< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:34 GMT
<< "{"name":"executeScript","sessionId":"bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38","status":0,"value":null}"
Connection 0.0.0.0:59281<->127.0.0.1:7055 shut down
Released connection is not reusable.
Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Connection 0.0.0.0:59281<->127.0.0.1:7055 closed
Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055, timeout = 120000
[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 47[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> Accept: application/json, image/png
>> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Length: 47
>> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "{"args":[""],"script":"window.scrollBy(0,200)"}"
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
<< "connection: close[\r][\n]"
<< "content-length: 99[\r][\n]"
<< "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
<< "date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:36 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<< connection: close
<< content-length: 99
<< server: httpd.js
<< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:36 GMT
<< "{"name":"executeScript","sessionId":"bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38","status":0,"value":null}"
Connection 0.0.0.0:59282<->127.0.0.1:7055 shut down
Released connection is not reusable.
Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Connection 0.0.0.0:59282<->127.0.0.1:7055 closed
Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055, timeout = 120000
[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 47[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> Accept: application/json, image/png
>> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Length: 47
>> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "{"args":[""],"script":"window.scrollBy(0,200)"}"
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
<< "connection: close[\r][\n]"
<< "content-length: 99[\r][\n]"
<< "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
<< "date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:36 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<< connection: close
<< content-length: 99
<< server: httpd.js
<< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:36 GMT
<< "{"name":"executeScript","sessionId":"bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38","status":0,"value":null}"
Connection 0.0.0.0:59283<->127.0.0.1:7055 shut down
Released connection is not reusable.
Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Connection 0.0.0.0:59283<->127.0.0.1:7055 closed
Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055, timeout = 120000
[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 47[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> Accept: application/json, image/png
>> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Length: 47
>> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "{"args":[""],"script":"window.scrollBy(0,200)"}"
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
<< "connection: close[\r][\n]"
<< "content-length: 99[\r][\n]"
<< "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
<< "date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:40 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<< connection: close
<< content-length: 99
<< server: httpd.js
<< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:40 GMT
<< "{"name":"executeScript","sessionId":"bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38","status":0,"value":null}"
Connection 0.0.0.0:59284<->127.0.0.1:7055 shut down
Released connection is not reusable.
Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Connection 0.0.0.0:59284<->127.0.0.1:7055 closed
Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055, timeout = 120000
[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 47[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> Accept: application/json, image/png
>> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Length: 47
>> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "{"args":[""],"script":"window.scrollBy(0,200)"}"
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
<< "connection: close[\r][\n]"
<< "content-length: 99[\r][\n]"
<< "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
<< "date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:40 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<< connection: close
<< content-length: 99
<< server: httpd.js
<< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:43:40 GMT
<< "{"name":"executeScript","sessionId":"bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38","status":0,"value":null}"
Connection 0.0.0.0:59285<->127.0.0.1:7055 shut down
Released connection is not reusable.
Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Connection 0.0.0.0:59285<->127.0.0.1:7055 closed
Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7055, timeout = 120000
[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Attempt 1 to execute request
Sending request: POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1
>> "POST /hub/session/bfaec653-501a-401c-9b6a-227341e1fe38/execute HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 47[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: The output you show, does not come from the code you posted.

Comment: I am using selenium to get pages, may be this log is because of that. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `rootLogger` to `DEBUG`, this means that debug statements of *all* libraries using Log4J will have their debug statements logged. This is probably the part of your code that you have replaced with the comment *`// Here is some process that performs recursively`*

It would probably be better to configure the `rootLogger` to log `INFO` or higher, and -if you actually need debug-level logging - configure the logger for this specific package  to `DEBUG`, using:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE
log4j.some.package = DEBUG
```

Where `some.package` is the package of your class. But as you're currently logging on info-level anyway that isn't really necessary.

Comment: Can I ask one problem, please ?

Comment: You can always ask a question, but you should consider whether or not your shouldn't just create a new question.

Comment: Actually I have another problem, that I asked here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919602/how-to-optimize-the-scroll-down-code-in-java-using-selenium   If you can, please answer this question, because this is also one part of my project, where I stucked. Please help me in that.